# Mount R/O partition as R/W for write and then set back to R/O in C

Tags: c++, c, linux, embedded

I need to write files to the /etc folder on an embedded system with the root partition mounted as Read Only and have them persist. Can I do this in C or C++ assuming that the application is running as root?

Comment: If the r/o partition is in ROM, you cannot. Its a specific question per your device, its impossible to answer it in a generic response

Comment: @littleadv It is a compact 44pin IDE flash. It is a jfs partion mounted as Read only.

Comment: Then I'm guessing you tried just running `mount` and it failed, right? Otherwise you wouldn't even ask, right?

Comment: @littleadv I am asking because I haven't the slightest clue about how file systems work.

Comment: I haven't tried mount, That might be the part I was asking someone to tell me how to do.

Comment: then superuser.SE would be  a better place, IMHO

Comment: @littleadv I really just want to know how to do it in code at the moment. That is why I chose SO

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always do the obvious:

```
system("mount -o remount,rw /etc");
```

Most embedded systems should be complete enough that mount is available.

Comment: This will only remount the directory /etc but not the entire partition?

Comment: The whole partition. If /etc is not a separate partition, replace by "/" (naturally). And a rw-remount works if the underlying filesystem is theoretically writeable (no read-only medium) and overrides an ro flag.

Comment: I actually just tried making /etc its own partition and it would not let me. Anyhow, so I need to just run mount -o remount, rw / and then when I am finished run mount -o remount, ro /   ?

Comment: Will this take up a significant amount of resources?

Answer (score 4):

> Can I do this in C or C++ assuming that the application is running as
>   root?

As mentioned, you can do :

```
system("mount -o remount,rw /etc");
```

but there is also the [mount](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mount) function to do this.